# ext.net mvc demo build under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, ext.net

I'm trying to use [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net/) with a MVC project in VS2010 but having problems getting the controls to show up (works fine on a regular web project).

There is a Ext.Net demo application [here](http://code.google.com/p/extnet-mvc/) that demonstrates how to build a ext.net MVC application but I'm having trouble building it under Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone know if it is possible to build the demo under Visual Studio 2010?

The error is:

No overload for method "Build" takes 5 arguments on this line in PartialViewRendered.cs:

```
string wScript = DefaultScriptBuilder.Create(p).Build(RenderMode.RenderTo, ct, null, true, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext.Net.Mvc works with latest version of Ext.Net are available in SVN only
You have to wait Ext.Net RC2

Comment: Thanks for that, I look forward to the release of RC2. In the mean time, I managed to get it to compile by removing one of the parameters on the above line.

Comment: We got it to compile also by swapping out the DLLs in there for the ones from the Ext.NET site.. I can't recall any such issues as you describe though.

Answer (score 0):

Faced that issue couple of months back, basically there is some route that you need to disable in MVC so that the controls can work i guess, not at work today, but will post it tomorrow.